# How can I check if a firebase Reference is empty before fetching it?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch a specific document from firebase. If it exists, great. But if it doesn't, I don't want it to break my app. I just want it to move on. However, I can't seem to shake off this error:

[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUehB.png)

Here is my code:

```
async function getOtherInfo() {
        //get profile image, username if they exist
    
        const profileRef = doc(db, "profiles", email);
       
        const snap = await getDoc(profileRef);
        if (snap.exists()) {
          setProfileImg(snap.data().profileImg);
          setUserName(snap.data().userName);
        }
```

Firebase gurus, please help me, I'm going crazy soon. Thanks a bunch.

edit: added code sections to show where my db and email state is coming from. Both are valid.

```
//init services
const db = getFirestore();

const [email, setEmail] = useState(identifier.email)
```

Comment: Please share your complete code so we can see all the imports and where values of `db` and `email` are coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If think you'r looking for:

```
if (email) { // 
    //get profile image, username if they exist

    const profileRef = doc(db, "profiles", email);
   
    const snap = await getDoc(profileRef);
    if (snap.exists()) {
      setProfileImg(snap.data().profileImg);
      setUserName(snap.data().userName);
    }
```

This ensure that you only try to load the document if there actually *is* an `email` value.